# Computing logarithm

Tags: python

I must write a function that computes the logarithm of a number `x` relative to a base `b` (rounded down if the answer is not an integer). I wrote this function but it's not working

```
def myLog(x, b):

    result = 1
    if b > x :    
        result -= 1
        return result
    elif x == b  :    
        return result
    else :
        result += 1
        b *= result
        return myLog(x,b)
```

Comment: What is it that you expect to happen?  What doesn't work?  Can you give us an example?

Comment: I can tell you that the whole use of result is a distraction right now.  Your first if is returning 0, the second is returning 1, and the third is multiplying b by 2 and returning myLog recursively.  This means you can only ever get an answer of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you multiplying the base by result and changing the base? When you determine that the base fits into the input number, you should be dividing the number by the base. Since the division means the final number is 1 more, you add 1 to the result of the recursive call.

```
def myLog(x, b):
    result = 1
    if b > x:
            result -= 1
            return result
    elif x == b:
            return result
    else:
            x /= b
            return 1 + myLog(x, b)
```

Example: myLog(32, 2):
32/2 = 16, add 1 to answer
16/2 = 8, add 1 to answer
...
answer = 5

Some of the code is unnecessary though, and I would further edit it to be this:

```
def myLog(x, b):
    if b > x:
            return 0
    elif x == b:
            return 1
    else:
            x /= b
            return 1 + myLog(x, b)
```